# How to Improve Mac OS Spell Checking?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, spell-check, osx-el-capitan

I've recently switched to Mac and although I like it overall but many useful features just don't seem to work. One example is the spell-checker. Most often it gives me no suggestions at all whereas I can get suggestion for the same spelling in MS word on my windows laptop (note: MS word on my Mac doesn't work effectively either). For instance, look at the example below:

1."Sophicistated" spelled in-correctly in Pages:

[image: A screenshot from the pages app on Mac]

2. "Sophicistated" spelled in-correctly in TextEdit:

[image]

3. "Sophicistated" spelled in-correctly in MS word:

[image]

Now, although I don't have my windows laptop with me right now but I grabbed a screenshot from MS Word's onlne editor on skydrive and that seems to work perfectly.

[image]

Google docs also works equally efficiently. This is not just one example, after seeing it not work for countless spellings I'm finally posting it here.

Foremost, I wonder why MS Word doesn't work with same effectiveness in Mac.

Are there any ways to improve the accuracy and effectiveness of the Mac spell checker?

Comment: Isn't it Sophisticated?

Comment: You question is confusing. Do you mean that Word doesn't work properly as Mac spell checked or the opposite? From the screenshots it seems Word is the only one working properly.

Comment: Spell check in general doesn't work that well on Mac, irrespective of the applicaiton used. At least, that's what my understanding is. I've tried a couple of apps (including the Mac Pages app, MS Word app on Mac, TextEdit etc.) but none of them work as good as spelling suggestion provided by apps on other platforms for instance, Google docs, MS Word on Windows etc.