# HDD & bad sectors, how are they handled?

Tags: hard-drive, storage, bad-sectors

Currently, I have 2 Seagate HDDs that are bad and I want to know how the Seatools, or another application, deal with these bad sectors.

As far as I know, bad sectors are some tiny sectors of the disk itself that are not possible to be accessed anymore.

But when I "fix" these sectors, what really happens? The tool "says" to the Windows (or another system) that these sectors could not be used anymore and skip them?

Or this information about the sectors to be skipped is stored in the firmware/HDD itself?

If I format an HDD with bad sectors and then run the application that "fix" bad sectors and after I format again, this information about sectors to skip will be lost?

A full format with 0/1 erases this information?

If I "fix" an HDD and then move it to another OS, or even to a PS3/PS4, this new OS will try to use these sectors?

Comment: The best answer is already given here: https://superuser.com/questions/1013338/remove-bad-sectors-on-a-hard-disk-in-windows-10/1016213#1016213

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which HDDs exactly you have, but all modern harddisks have "spare sectors" that they will use instead of a bad sector on the next write to the bad sector. You don't have to use any tools for that to happen, the HDD firmware takes care of it.

> As far as I know, bad sectors are some tiny sectors of the disk itself that are not possible to be accessed anymore.

Now, bad sectors are just ordinary sectors in a place where the surface of the harddisk has gone so bad that you cannot properly write data anymore, or, where additional information "around" that sector has become corrupted, and since this additional information is only written when the harddisk is produced, that cannot be fixed.

> Or this information about the sectors to be skipped are store in the firmware/HDD itself?

I am not familiar with Seatools, but possibly the can trigger a reallocation directly, using undocumented commands.

You can see the reallocation count in the SMART information that all modern harddisks provide.

> If I format an HDD with bad sectors

You cannot really format modern harddisks. As a wrote above, this normally only happens when the harddisk is manufactured. "Formatting" by the OS just means "write something to all sectors". Again, Seatools may potentially allow this; but I'd be surprised if it does.

> If I "fix" an HDD and then move it to another OS, or even to a PS3/PS4, this new OS will try to use these sectors?

The reallocation of "spare" sectors to be used instead of "bad" sectors happens in the firmware. It's completely transparent to any OS using the harddisk; the OS won't even know that this happened.

Comment: So, If I run the tool to reallocate these sectors, or skip them, when I check again the disk, the tool should show these sectors again as faulty or the disk will ignore them as if they not exist?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, and I guess it depends on the tool. Any tools that do not use vendor-specific secret commands will either get an error on reading a bad sector, or, after writing to this sector once, will get no error for the same sector. In particular, tools on the OS-level that deal with bad sectors make no sense for modern harddisks. TL;DR: Don't worry about bad sectors, you can't do anything about them. 30 years ago you'd have to, but that time is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Please name the supposed tool and the function of the tool that is supposed to fix your drive because there is no genuine fixing of sectors.

When communicating low level with a drive you are giving instructions to read or write certain sectors.

If the drives fails on reading the relevant sector is classified internally in the hard drive as "pending". It stays in this state because a future read attempt might work.

If a write attempt on this pending sector succeeds it is not pending anymore. If the write attempt fails the sector will be redirected by a spare sector as long as there are available spare sectors in the spare pool. The sectors has then become "reallocated".
This behaviour is reasonable because writing means that you give up the previous content of the sector.

On a hard drive level view all this happens independently of what an operating system does with the sectors. There is no communication between the drive level and the file system level handled by the operating system with the exception being modern SSD drives where the operating system tells the drive (one level below) that certain sectors are currently not in use.

When talking about "fixing" a drive the only possible way would be to read each sector and rewrite it again to trigger the redirection mechanism in case of unreadable sectors.

But if the read operation fails you are kind of forging the content of the sector upon write because you have to write something, for instance zeros without knowing if this is the correct content.

This is easy to do if you give up the content of your drive.
For a drive that still contains data you have specialized software like Microsoft "chkdsk" for instance. That software is able to mark broken sectors on file system level (called clusters) to exclude them from using. But if that broken sector belongs to a file the operating system has to do something with it - I don't know what chkdsk would do. One possibility would be to simply delete it, another one would be to leave it untouched producing read errors upon a read attempt to that file. A third option would be to blacklist such a file to tell the user that something is broken.